# PHP: How to rename a file uploaded with Zend_Form_Element_File?

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-file

### Form:

```
//excerpt
$file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
$file->setLabel('File to upload:')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
    ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
    ->setDestination(APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR);
$this->addElement($file);
```

### Controller:

```
//excerpt
if ($form->isValid($request->getPost()) {
    $newFilename = 'foobar.txt';
    //how should I rename the file?
    //When should I rename the file? Before or after receiving?
    try {
        $form->file->receive();
        echo 'filename: '. $form->file->getFileName();
    }
}
```

### Questions:

1. When I call `$form->file->getFileName()` it returns the full path, not just the file name. How can I output just the name of the file?

   ```
   //Answer: First, get an array of the parts of the filename:
   $pathparts = pathinfo($form->file->getFileName());
   //then get the part that you want to use
   $originalFilename = $pathparts['basename'];
   ```
2. How can I rename the filename to something I want? Can this be done with the `Rename` filter? I'm already setting the destination in the form, so all I want to do is change the filename. Maybe I shouldn't be setting the destination in the form? Or maybe this can't be done with a filter. Maybe I should be doing this with a PHP function? What should I do?

   ```
   //Answer: Use the rename filter:
   $form->file->addFilter('Rename', 'new-file-name-goes-here.txt');
   ```

### Final Solution:

This is what I ended up doing:

```
public function foobarAction()
{
    //...etc...

    if (!$form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
        $this->view->form = $form;
        return;
    }

    //the following will rename the file (I'm setting the upload dir in the form)
    $originalFilename = pathinfo($form->file->getFileName());
    $newFilename = 'file-' . uniqid() . '.' . $originalFilename['extension'];
    $form->file->addFilter('Rename', $newFilename);

    try {
        $form->file->receive();
        //upload complete!
        $file = new Default_Model_File();
        $file->setDisplayFilename($originalFilename['basename'])
            ->setActualFilename($newFilename)
            ->setMimeType($form->file->getMimeType())
            ->setDescription($form->description->getValue());
        $file->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //error: file couldn't be received, or saved (one of the two)
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly the example i needed for renaming file uploads! thanks for posting your solution

Comment: I didn't even know it was possible to add a filter AFTER the file gets uploaded... Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer question 1, to get a filename from a full path, you can use [`basename`](http://php.net/basename), or [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo).

For example *(copy-paste from the doc)* :

```
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
```

Or :

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/index.html');
echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
```

To rename / move the file, I suppose [`rename`](http://php.net/rename) would do the trick, even if it's quite not "Zend Framework solution".

If the file has not been moved by ZF and is still in the temporary directory, you should use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) -- but as you are using `setDestination`, I suppose the file is no longer in the sytem's temporary directory.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [rename filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html#zend.file.transfer.filters.rename).

Answer (score 5):

Folks, here's a simple example of a form that uses [the rename filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html#zend.file.transfer.filters.rename) on a file after it's been uploaded. There are many more options and yes, you'd need to take in to consideration existing files, but to get you started, here you go.

When the file's uploaded through the form below, it will be renamed to '**config.ini**'.

```
$form = new Zend_Form;
$form->setAction('/default/index/file-upload')
     ->setMethod('post');

$uploadFile = new Zend_Form_Element_File('uploadfile');
$uploadFile->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(
              array('target' => 'config.ini'))
           )
           ->setRequired(true)
           ->setLabel('Upload file:');

$form->addElement($uploadFile);
$form->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit'));

if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
    $values = $form->getValues();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Easy fix to get Zend to rename before uploading**

The problem I address here is explained in more detail here: http://www.thomasweidner.com/flatpress/2009/04/17/recieving-files-with-zend_form_element_file/

I was having trouble getting the file to rename before uploading and found the solution for my scenario.  At some point Zend thought it clever to have the getValue() method of the file element upload the file for you.  Fortunately they added an option to disable this feature.

**Solution:**  If you are calling getValue() on the file element, or getValues() on the form, and you want to modify the name before it uploads you have to set setValueDisabled(true) on your Zend_Form_Element_File.

*Fyi: I don't claim this to be optimized, I just claim it to work for me*

**Creating the form element** (*magic inside*)

```
$uploadConfig = Zend_Registry::get('upload');
$fileuploader = new Zend_Form_Element_File('ugc_fileupload');
$fileuploader->setRequired(true);
$fileuploader->setLabel('*Upload File:');
$fileuploader->addValidator('Count', false, 1); // ensure only 1 file
$fileuploader->setValueDisabled(true); // ***THIS IS THE MAGIC***
$fileuploader->addValidator('Size', false, $uploadConfig['videomax']);
$fileuploader->addValidator('Extension', false, 'mov, avi, wmv, mp4');
$this->addElement($fileuploader, 'ugc_fileupload');
```

**Rename before uploading** (inside preUpload($form))

```
$uploadCfg = Zend_Registry::get('upload');

// Get the parts of the name
// Call to getValue() here was uploading the file before telling it not to!
$atiFile = $form->ugc_fileupload->getValue();
$fileExt = $this->getFileExtension($atiFile);
$nameBase = $this->getFileName($atiFile, $fileExt);
$fullName = $atiFile;
$fullPath = $uploadCfg['tmpdir'] . $fullName;

// Keep checking until the filename doesn't exist
$numToAdd = 0;
while(file_exists($fullPath)) {
  $fullName = $nameBase . $numToAdd . $fileExt;
  $fullPath = $uploadCfg['tmpdir'] . $fullName;
  $numToAdd++;
}

$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
// or $upload = $form->ugc_fileupload->getTransferAdapter();
// both work, I'm not sure if one is better than the other...

//Now that the file has not already been uploaded renaming works
$upload->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array(
  'target' =>  $fullPath,
  'overwrite' => false)
));

try {
  $upload->receive();
} catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
  //$e->getMessage()
}
```

**Helper methods**

```
public function getFileName($path, $ext) {
  return $bname = basename($path, $ext);
}

public function getFileExtension($path) {
  return $ext = strrchr($path, '.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult to do with Zend for a few reasons.

1. If you rename the file after it's been moved to the upload destination then it might've overwritten a file that you didn't want rewritten.

For example, say you have a destination directory called /path/to/my/pics. If two users, at the same time, upload a picture called 'me.png' then they might override each other. This is because the rename filter is applied AFTER the file is moved to /path/to/my/pics. Thus, it might not be renamed before it is overwritten by a new file upload.

1. If you use Zend's rename filter then you can't keep the original files extension.

The way I did it was to do the following,
1. Extend the http transfer adapter to pass the rename filter the original file name. The normal http transfer adapter passes in the temporary name in the tmp directory and does not have the file extension.

1. Extend the rename filter so that you can specify whether or not it should keep the original file extension.

Afterward, you'll have to add the prefix to the form you're using so that the form can find your adapter and so your adapter can find the new Rename filter you've made.

The reason I did it this way is because my destination directory was going to have one pic in it for every user where each pic was named 'user1.jpg' or 'user2.png'. I wanted to rename the file at the same time that I moved it so it wouldn't override any other files in the directory that I wanted to keep.

Here is the code I've used.

```
class My_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http
    extends Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http
{

    /**
     * Receive the file from the client (Upload)
     * This differs from the Zend adapter in that
     * the adapter passes in the files actual
     * name to the rename filter so that when
     * it is renamed, the renamer can use the extension
     * of the file and keep it or change it.
     *
     * @param  string|array $files (Optional) Files to receive
     * @return bool
     */
    public function receive($files = null)
    {
        if (!$this->isValid($files)) {
            return false;
        }

        $check = $this->_getFiles($files);
        foreach ($check as $file => $content) {
            if (!$content['received']) {
                $directory   = '';
                $destination = $this->getDestination($file);
                if ($destination !== null) {
                    $directory = $destination . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                }

                /******************************************/
                // The original transfer adapter
                // passes content['tmp_name']
                // but we'll pass in content['name'] instead
                // to have access to the extension
                /******************************************/


                $filename = $directory . $content['name'];
                $rename   = $this->getFilter('File_Rename');
                if ($rename !== null) {
                    $tmp = $rename->getNewName($content['name']);
                    if ($tmp != $content['name']) {
                        $filename = $tmp;
                    }

                    if (dirname($filename) == '.') {
                        $filename = $directory . $filename;
                    }

                    $key = array_search(get_class($rename), $this->_files[$file]['filters']);
                    unset($this->_files[$file]['filters'][$key]);
                }

                // Should never return false when it's tested by the upload validator
                if (!move_uploaded_file($content['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
                    if ($content['options']['ignoreNoFile']) {
                        $this->_files[$file]['received'] = true;
                        $this->_files[$file]['filtered'] = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    $this->_files[$file]['received'] = false;
                    return false;
                }

                if ($rename !== null) {
                    $this->_files[$file]['destination'] = dirname($filename);
                    $this->_files[$file]['name']        = basename($filename);
                }

                $this->_files[$file]['tmp_name'] = $filename;
                $this->_files[$file]['received'] = true;
            }

            if (!$content['filtered']) {
                if (!$this->_filter($file)) {
                    $this->_files[$file]['filtered'] = false;
                    return false;
                }

                $this->_files[$file]['filtered'] = true;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

That is the adapter, now for the filter.

```
class My_Filter_File_Rename
    extends Zend_Filter_File_Rename
{

    /**
     * Internal array of array(source, target, overwrite)
     */
    protected $_files = array( );

    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     * Options argument may be either a string, a Zend_Config object, or an array.
     * If an array or Zend_Config object, it accepts the following keys:
     * 'source'    => Source filename or directory which will be renamed
     * 'target'    => Target filename or directory, the new name of the sourcefile
     * 'overwrite' => Shall existing files be overwritten ?
     * 'keepExtension' => Should the files original extension be kept
     *
     * @param  string|array $options Target file or directory to be renamed
     * @param  string $target Source filename or directory (deprecated)
     * @param  bool $overwrite Should existing files be overwritten (deprecated)
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct( $options )
    {
        if( $options instanceof Zend_Config )
        {
            $options = $options->toArray();
        }
        elseif( is_string( $options ) )
        {
            $options = array( 'target' => $options );
        }
        elseif( !is_array( $options ) )
        {
            require_once 'Zend/Filter/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Filter_Exception( 'Invalid options argument provided to filter' );
        }

        if( 1 setFile( $options );
    }

    /**
     * Returns the files to rename and their new name and location
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->_files;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a new file or directory as target, deleting existing ones
     *
     * Array accepts the following keys:
     * 'source'    => Source filename or directory which will be renamed
     * 'target'    => Target filename or directory, the new name of the sourcefile
     * 'overwrite' => Shall existing files be overwritten ?
     * 'keepExtension' => Should the files original extension be kept
     *
     * @param  string|array $options Old file or directory to be rewritten
     * @return Zend_Filter_File_Rename
     */
    public function setFile( $options )
    {
        $this->_files = array( );
        $this->addFile( $options );

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new file or directory as target to the existing ones
     *
     * Array accepts the following keys:
     * 'source'    => Source filename or directory which will be renamed
     * 'target'    => Target filename or directory, the new name of the sourcefile
     * 'overwrite' => Shall existing files be overwritten ?
     * 'keepExtension' => Should the files original extension be kept
     *
     * @param  string|array $options Old file or directory to be rewritten
     * @return Zend_Filter_File_Rename
     */
    public function addFile( $options )
    {
        if( is_string( $options ) )
        {
            $options = array( 'target' => $options );
        }
        elseif( !is_array( $options ) )
        {
            require_once 'Zend/Filter/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Filter_Exception( 'Invalid options to rename filter provided' );
        }

        $this->_convertOptions( $options );

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns only the new filename without moving it
     * But existing files will be erased when the overwrite option is true
     *
     * @param  string  $value  Full path of file to change
     * @param  boolean $source Return internal informations
     * @return string The new filename which has been set
     */
    public function getNewName( $value,
                                $source = false )
    {
        $file = $this->_getFileName( $value );
        if( $file[ 'source' ] == $file[ 'target' ] )
        {
            return $value;
        }

        if( !file_exists( $file[ 'source' ] ) && !$file['keepExtension'] )
        {
            return $value;
        }

        if( ($file[ 'overwrite' ] == true) && (file_exists( $file[ 'target' ] )) )
        {
            unlink( $file[ 'target' ] );
        }

        if( file_exists( $file[ 'target' ] ) )
        {
            require_once 'Zend/Filter/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Filter_Exception( sprintf( "File '%s' could not be renamed. It already exists.",
                                                      $value ) );
        }

        if( $source )
        {
            return $file;
        }

        return $file[ 'target' ];
    }

    /**
     * Defined by Zend_Filter_Interface
     *
     * Renames the file $value to the new name set before
     * Returns the file $value, removing all but digit characters
     *
     * @param  string $value Full path of file to change
     * @throws Zend_Filter_Exception
     * @return string The new filename which has been set, or false when there were errors
     */
    public function filter( $value )
    {
        $file = $this->getNewName( $value, true );
        if( is_string( $file ) )
        {
            return $file;
        }

        $result = rename( $file[ 'source' ], $file[ 'target' ] );

        if( $result === true )
        {
            return $file[ 'target' ];
        }

        require_once 'Zend/Filter/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Filter_Exception( sprintf( "File '%s' could not be renamed. An error occured while processing the file.",
                                                  $value ) );
    }

    /**
     * Internal method for creating the file array
     * Supports single and nested arrays
     *
     * @param  array $options
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _convertOptions( $options )
    {
        $files = array( );
        foreach( $options as $key => $value )
        {
            if( is_array( $value ) )
            {
                $this->_convertOptions( $value );
                continue;
            }

            switch( $key )
            {
                case "source":
                    $files[ 'source' ] = ( string ) $value;
                    break;

                case 'target' :
                    $files[ 'target' ] = ( string ) $value;
                    break;

                case 'overwrite' :
                    $files[ 'overwrite' ] = ( boolean ) $value;
                    break;
                case 'keepExtension':
                    $files[ 'keepExtension' ] = ( boolean ) $value;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        if( empty( $files ) )
        {
            return $this;
        }

        if( empty( $files[ 'source' ] ) )
        {
            $files[ 'source' ] = '*';
        }

        if( empty( $files[ 'target' ] ) )
        {
            $files[ 'target' ] = '*';
        }

        if( empty( $files[ 'overwrite' ] ) )
        {
            $files[ 'overwrite' ] = false;
        }

        if( empty( $files[ 'keepExtension' ] ) )
        {
            $files[ 'keepExtension' ] = true;
        }


        $found = false;
        foreach( $this->_files as $key => $value )
        {
            if( $value[ 'source' ] == $files[ 'source' ] )
            {
                $this->_files[ $key ] = $files;
                $found = true;
            }
        }

        if( !$found )
        {
            $count = count( $this->_files );
            $this->_files[ $count ] = $files;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to resolve the requested source
     * and return all other related parameters
     *
     * @param  string $file Filename to get the informations for
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getFileName( $file )
    {
        $rename = array( );
        foreach( $this->_files as $value )
        {
            if( $value[ 'source' ] == '*' )
            {
                if( !isset( $rename[ 'source' ] ) )
                {
                    $rename = $value;
                    $rename[ 'source' ] = $file;
                }
            }

            if( $value[ 'source' ] == $file )
            {
                $rename = $value;
            }
        }

        if( !isset( $rename[ 'source' ] ) )
        {
            return $file;
        }

        if( !isset( $rename[ 'target' ] ) or ($rename[ 'target' ] == '*') )
        {
            $rename[ 'target' ] = $rename[ 'source' ];
        }

        if( is_dir( $rename[ 'target' ] ) )
        {
            $name = basename( $rename[ 'source' ] );
            $last = $rename[ 'target' ][ strlen( $rename[ 'target' ] ) - 1 ];
            if( ($last != '/') and ($last != '\\') )
            {
                $rename[ 'target' ] .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            }

            $rename[ 'target' ] .= $name;
        }

        if( !is_dir( $rename['target'] ) || $rename[ 'keepExtension' ] )
        {
            $name = basename( $rename[ 'source' ] );
            $parts = explode( '.', $name );
            $extension = $parts[count( $parts ) - 1];

            $rename[ 'target' ] .= '.' . $extension;
        }
        return $rename;
    }

}
```

You'll then have to add the prefix path's to the file element that you've made to upload the file.

```
$fileElement->addPrefixPath('My_File_Transfer_Adapter', 'My/File/Transfer/Adapter', Zend_Form_Element_File::TRANSFER_ADAPTER );

$fileElement->addPrefixPath( 'My_Filter', 'My/Filter', Zend_Form_Element_File::FILTER );
```

When you add the filter to the file element you'll have to do it the following way

```
$fileElement->addFilter(
                        'File_Rename',
                        array(
                            'target' => $this->_getPictureDestination() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "user$userId",
                            'overwrite' => true,
                            'keepExtension' => true
                        )
            )
```

Now, when the files get moved over to the new directory they'll have the original files extension and they'll have the new name that you specified when you added the filter to the file element.

If this was hard to understand please let me know. It took me a while to figure out what was going on in Zend to do this so if it helps anyone, use this code freely.

Comment: +1 this is definitely the correct route to take.  Nicely done.

Comment: In your filter I think you have a bogus line in the constructor at the very end `if( 1 setFile( $options );`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the comments @LesterPeabody. I'll have to look at the file again to double check this. I forgot what this should be.

Comment: I do have a question.  What is the purpose of the `addPrefixPath(...)` step?  I'm completely new to Zend by the way.

Comment: The addPrefixPath will tell the element where to find a class when looking for it. Normally the elements will only look in the default Zend locations. Since this is 'your' code, you want to tell the element how to find your code and load the class.

Comment: How does it know to use your file over the default file though?  I think addPrefixPath just adds it to an existing list of files?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something slightly different then you did.  I'm creating the file element by calling `createElemene` from a Zend_Form object.  This probably uses some default path.  When I specify my path though (the path to My_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http file) the same behavior is experience as if I didn't even add my path.  Thoughts?  I copied your adapter verbatim.

Comment: Yeah I just confirmed that it's using the regular Zend HTTP Transfer adapter.  I changed the same lines in it that you have above and I'm getting the correct file output.  Weird.

Comment: I would have to go through the code again because it took a bit of digging to figure out, but you have to add the prefix path to the element. Each one keeps its own path. When you call `addFilter( 'File_Rename' ` ...etc, the element looks into each of the prefix paths it has. If it finds something named File_Rename it will load it. Since your path is on 'top' of the default it finds yours first. It's a weird quirk in Zend. You'll have to break the directory structure a bit and place the filter file in the My\Filter directory with the name of File_Rename.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24075/discussion-between-jerry-saravia-and-lester-peabody)

Answer (score 1):

**//  For Zend Framework :: Rename Uploaded File**

```
 $renameFile = 'newName.jpg';

 $fullFilePath = '/images/'.$renameFile;

 // Rename uploaded file using Zend Framework
 $filterFileRename = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array('target' => $fullFilePath, 'overwrite' => true));

 $filterFileRename -> filter($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rename filter. If you want to rename your filename during uploading maybe it helps you.

First we need a function rename or remove unwanted characters from your filename for example use this.

```
public function simple_fileformat($str)
{
    $str = preg_replace("{[^A-Za-z0-9_]\.}", "", $str);
    $str = str_replace(" ", "_", $str);
    return $str;
}
```

After that you can use the above function for renaming.

```
$filename = new Zend_Form_Element_File("filename");
$filename->setLabel("filename");
$filename->setRequired(true);
$filename->setDestination($doc_path);
$filename->addFilter("rename", $doc_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->simple_fileformat(basename($filename->getFileName())));
```

That is easy. Is not it?